C Declaration with Self-Assignment Compiles
I was extremely surprised that the following C-code compiles:
int foo() {
    int x = x;
    return x;
}

Is this guaranteed to compile?  Is the value of x defined after the assignment (it was zero when I tested in GCC)?

gcc, no optimizations - compiles with no complaints, undefined value, gcc O3 - compiles with no complaints and value zero, clang - compiles with warning about uninitialized

I suspect it only compiles on GCC if you have set very relaxed warning levels. Other C compilers will likely return the constant value for an uninitialised variable or runtime trap if they will compile it at all. It may compile but it will still have undefined behaviour.

I guess clang wins this one

This code has undefined behavior.
The x on the right of the = serving as an initializer is itself uninitialized at the time it is used.  Reading an uninitialized value that has never had its address taken causes undefined behavior as per section 6.3.2.1p2 of the C standard:

Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof
operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or
the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an
lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored
in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called
lvalue conversion. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the
unqualified version of the type of the lvalue; additionally, if the
lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version of the
type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue.
If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the
behavior is undefined. If the lvalue designates an object of
automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the
register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment
to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.


According to that definition, the object is not uninitialized because it is declared with an initializer, so the fact that no assignment has been performed is irrelevant

@Artyer But x has not been initialized yet at the time the initializer is read.

That's not what the quote says but this appears to be a standard defect because "uninitialized" is used one more time in C2x §6.7.9 example 2 (Draft: n3096) and double b = b*b;  // undefined, uses uninitialized variable without address is the example.
